# PHP - What is modifying my .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

On my php server I modified my .htaccess file to include .html .htm. This works well and allows me to run a little php on some of my .html files. The issue is every few days my .htaccess file reverts back to the original file and all my php code becomes publicly visible and the site fails to load correctly. Tech support advise they do not change anything on my site.

Is there a way for me to run some form of ongoing script which monitors a file to see what process on my server is making this unwanted change?

I've removed write access to file as a temp workaround. Looked at modified times and done some Google searching for a solution. Wordpress seems to have a similar issue but I'm not using wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question that is better asked in the [Linux site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), if your server runs Linux.

You can find a nice answer at [Find which process is modifying a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99074/find-which-process-is-modifying-a-file), it should help you find the culprit easy enough.